# Select all rows in a table using JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How do I select all rows in a table without the user selecting them with mouse? For example, I have at a table called `InputTable`. Using `ActionListener`/`TableModelListener`, I can get the selected rows (when the user clicks on them) in a table somewhat in this way:

```
int[] rows = inputTable.getSelectedRows();
```

I would now like to select all the rows in the Input table and assign it to say, `int [] rows1`. Is there a command like `getSelectedRows()` where I can select all the rows without the user interaction? I know that there is a `SelectAll()` but I want something specific to the rows alone.

Comment: `table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, table.getModel().getRowCount()-1);`?

Comment: could you explain this in more detail?

Comment: @SwethaP: it's described in details in the javadoc. Read it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29. That's the whole point of javadoc: being read by developers.

Comment: Yes. But my question was to get something like int[] rows = inputTable.getSelectedRows(); where I can store the indexes of the selected rows in an array.

Comment: Okay, obviously we are missing the point of the question.  You KNOW how to `selectAll`, you've been shown how to `setRowSelectionInterval` to select only a range of rows and you KNOW how to `getSelectedRows` what's the question??

Comment: The point is, **selectAll** and **setRowSelectionInterval** are **void** methods. They do not return anything right? I would like to know if there are any methods that work like **getSelectedRows** which returns the row indexes which can then be stored in an array.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion I wasn't clear before.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to progamatically select *rows* of a `JTable`.

The `JTable` is just a display mechanism. Instead of selecting rows in the table (view), you select rows in the [`SelectionModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html), so have a look at this small example I made:

[image]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents(frame);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {

        String data[][] = {
            {"1", "2", "3"},
            {"4", "5", "6"},
            {"7", "8", "9"},
            {"10", "11", "12"}
        };

        String col[] = {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        //call method to select rows (select all rows)
        selectRows(table, 0, table.getRowCount());

        //call method to return values of selected rows
        ArrayList<Integer> values = getSelectedRowValues(table);

        //prints out each values of the selected rows
        for (Integer integer : values) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    private void selectRows(JTable table, int start, int end) {
        // Use this mode to demonstrate the following examples
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        // Needs to be set or rows cannot be selected
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        // Select rows from start to end if start is 0 we change to 1 or leave it (used to preserve coloums headers)
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(start, end - 1);
    }

    /**
     * Will return all selected rows values
     *
     * @param table
     * @return ArrayList<Intger> values of each selected row for all coloumns
     */
    private ArrayList<Integer> getSelectedRowValues(JTable table) {
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] vals = table.getSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < table.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                System.out.println(table.getValueAt(i, x));
                values.add(Integer.parseInt((String) table.getValueAt(i, x)));
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

The magic happens here:

```
    private void selectRows(JTable table, int start, int end) {
        // Use this mode to demonstrate the following examples
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        // Needs to be set or rows cannot be selected
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        // Select rows from start to end if start is 0 we change to 1 or leave it (used to preserve coloums headers)
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(start, end - 1);
    }
```

For more examples have a look [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/Sel.html) shows you how to use `SelectionModel` on `JTable` for rows and colomns

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a previous (or desired) selection stored, and you want to restore that selection:

```
int[] rowsToSelect = inputTable.getSelectedRows();
```

You can set or restore this selection at a later time or to another table:

```
final ListSelectionModel sm = inputTable.getSelectionModel();
sm.clearSelection(); // First clear selection

for ( final int idx : rowsToSelect )
    sm.addSelectionInterval( idx, idx ); // Make this row selected
```

**Note:** You can improve performance if you first sort the indices, and call `addSelectionInterval()` with continuous index ranges:

```
Arrays.sort( rowsToSelect );  // You only have to sort if it is not yet sorted

final ListSelectionModel sm = inputTable.getSelectionModel();
sm.clearSelection(); // First clear selection

int rangeFirst = -1, previous = -1;
for ( final int idx : rowsToSelect ) {
    if ( rangeFirst < 0 )
        previous = rangeFirst = idx; // Start an index range
    else if ( idx != previous + 1 ) {
        // A continuous index range ends here, make it selected
        sm.addSelectionInterval( rangeFirst, previous );
        previous = rangeFirst = idx; // Start a new index range
    }
    else
       previous = idx; // Index range is continuous, proceed to the next index
}

// Add the last range which is not handled by the for loop:
if ( rangeFirst >= 0 )
    sm.addSelectionInterval( rangeFirst, previous );
```

**Final note:** If you want/have to select the same indices many times, it is profitable to store the continuous ranges so you don't have to detect them each time. Basically this means to store the ranges you pass to the `sm.addSelectionInterval()` method in the code sample above:

```
Arrays.sort( rowsToSelect );  // You only have to sort if it is not yet sorted

// Detect and store continuous index ranges:
final List< int[] > idxRangeList = new ArrayList< int[] >();

int rangeFirst = -1, previous = -1;
for ( final int idx : rowsToSelect ) {
    if ( rangeFirst < 0 )
        previous = rangeFirst = idx; // Start an index range
    else if ( idx != previous + 1 ) {
        // A continuous index range ends here, store it
        idxRangeList.add( new int[] { rangeFirst, previous } );
        previous = rangeFirst = idx; // Start a new index range
    }
    else
       previous = idx; // Index range is continuous, proceed to the next index
}

// Add the last range which is not handled by the for loop:
if ( rangeFirst >= 0 )
     idxRangeList.add( new int[] { rangeFirst, previous } );

// And now if you want those ranges selected:
final ListSelectionModel sm = inputTable.getSelectionModel();
sm.clearSelection(); // First clear selection

for ( final int[] range : idxRangeList )
    sm.addSelectionInterval( range[ 0 ], range[ 1 ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do the selectAll() function in the constructor it should select the hole table without any user interaction.

```
  private void createAndShowUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initComponents(frame);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    table.selectAll();
}
```